# Where should Business Delegate & Service Locator reside to not have circular dependency in this case?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am working with Java 1.7, XDoclet 1.2.3, WildFly 8.2.1.Final, Dynamic Web Module 2.5, EJB 2.1 in Eclipse Luna.

- I have an Enterprise Application project named
  **P001_EAR**.
- I have a Dynamic Web Project named **P001_WAR**.
- I have a EJB Project named **P001_EJB**.
- I have a EJB Client Project named **P001_EJBClient**.
- I have a Utility Project named **P001_SRC**.

The **P001_SRC** contains the data layer, domain objects, business interface, helper classes.

The **P001_EJB** has Stateless Session EJBs which implements the business interface. It has a reference of **P001_SRC**.

The **P001_EJBClient** contains the remote and home interfaces of EJBs. It has a reference of **P001_SRC**.

The **P001_WAR** contains web stuff listeners, filters, servlets, JSPs, HTMLs. It has a reference of **P001_SRC**.

This is a typical scenario:

JSP call Servlet, Servlet call `Business Delegate`, `Business Delegate` call EJB (using ServiceLocator), EJB perform business operation.

Question is where to put `Business Delegate`?

I was thinking of putting them in **P001_SRC** but `Business Delegate` needs a reference to **P001_EJBClient** to perform their actions and that means a circular dependency.

How you would solve this issue?

Also the issue is to where to put the Service Locator? Would it go in the same project as `Business Delegate`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a classic J2EE design pattern, the each client module of the EJB would have its own Business Delegate, which knows about the actual EJB. In your scenario, it would be in the WAR (as it's the client of the EJB). Similarly, your Service Locator would reside along with your Business Delegate and provide data about where your EJB is.

But seriously, is this some kind of exercise or school/interview question? Or are we traveling back in time? :-)

If this is for a new application, I would seriously consider moving away from EJB 2.x in favor of EJB 3.x, as it simplifies *a lot*. You can't even say that you "can't move", as you are already using an application server that supports EJB 3.x.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice regarding WAR being client of EJB makes total sense. This is work related but not a new application. Company has an enterprise app build with EJB 2.x and running on JBoss 4.x and is looking at upgrading it to WildFly 8.x without upgrading EJB to 3.x.